# Comprobar que los campos solo lectura no han sido modificados

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, spring, spring-mvc

estoy utilizando spring-mvc y tengo un formulario en una jsp , en este formulario hay campos que son solo lectura, imaginemos que tenemos que hacer un pago y un campo es el importe, me gustaria saber como puedo hacer para comprobar que los campos solo lectura no han sido cambiados.

Answer (score 2):

Si estas trabajando con Spring yo te recomiendo trabajar con Validaciones de grupo en Spring (@Validated).

Si haces una clase que implemente Validator y sea injectada a través del @InitBinder esta clase intercepta la petición a la clase de tipo controller pudiendo hacer validaciones estandard(regex, not null,....) pero también llamar a la base de datos o a un servicio web y comprobar si esos datos son correctos y han sido modificados.

Si me pones el ejemplo concreto te puedo decir las modificaciones que tienes que hacer en el xml del context y en resto de archivos.

Comment: Valeee, muchas graciaas, con esto me ha valido de momento para hacerme una idea, de momento no tengo el codigo implementado porque no queria empezar a picar codigo a lo tonto, queria tener una idea. Graciaas

Answer (score 1):

Hay diferentes manera de hacer esto pero lo via mas facil es ponerle a los input que son de lectura que sean disabled asi el usuario no podra modificarlos

Comment: Pero si quiere el usuario podria cambiar el html, o para la request y cambiarlo... no?

Comment: bueno si lo miras asi si, otra opcion es crear input hidden y guardar los datos en esos input ya por ahi puedes verificar si hay algun cambio con los input de lectura. Otra manera de aserlo en vez de hacer input de tipo hidden es guardar los elementos que no pueden ser cambiados en un arreglo.

Comment: Pero se volveria a estar en las mismas, el usuario puede abrir el html y cambiar el de solo lectura y el hidden?

Comment: Y la de guardar los elementos en un arreglo

Answer (score 1):

Personalmente recomiendo que si vas a tener un campo donde mostrar los resultados de un cálculo, no los coloques como inputs "readonly", sino como elementos `div` o `span` que actualices cuando sea necesario.

Pero lo más importante es que los registros que estés haciendo los almacenes como variables de sesión si te es posible, ya que el Javascript es vulnerable en estos casos.